# Laravel Eloquent Model Unbindings

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have recently started using Laravel and I would like to know if there is a way to unbind model relationships in specific calls. For example if one of my models got a hasOne binding, I have a particular call that I don't want that relationship to be retrieved to eliminate extra database calls. I know that this is possible in CakePHP but haven't found a way to do it in Laravel yet.

Thanks

Comment: Relationships are not fetched unless you call them (dynamic properties) or load (lazy loading / eager loading).

Comment: It would help to see some code.  Have you tried simply not querying the related data?  http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#querying-relations.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk The related models seems to be available therefore I am assuming that they are being retrieved automatically.

So I have a User model with this in it:

public function UserTransaction()
{
   return $this->hasMany('UserTransaction');
}

$user->userTransaction is automatically available to use when doing:

$user = User::find(1); for example

Comment: @KerstenJamesChircop Like I said, related models are fetched when you call the relation as dynamic property or eager/lazy load (using `load` or `with` method) - read this http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#dynamic-properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relationships in Laravel are only eager loaded if specified.  If you don't eager load the relationship, it will be lazy loaded the first time you try to access it, making it appear as if it had already be loaded.

User class:

```
class User extends Eloquent
{
    public function userTransactions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('UserTransaction');
    }
}
```

Eager loading:

```
// runs one query to get the user, and a second query to get the user
// transactions for the user
$user = User::with('userTransactions')->find(1);
```

Lazy loading:

```
// runs one query to get the user
$user = User::find(1);

// first time the userTransactions property is accessed, it runs the query
// to get the user transactions for the user.
print_r($user->userTransactions->lists('id'));
```

Comment: This helps clarifying the issue. Thanks!